# looping through array of inputs to set value, "cannot set property value of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, input, key-value

I'm looking for a plain-Javascript way to fix my following code:

```
function autoFill(response) {
    var arr = [];
    arr.fn = document.getElementsByName("firstName")[1];
    arr.ln = document.getElementsByName("lastName")[1];
    arr.em = document.getElementsByName("Email")[1];
    arr.pn = document.getElementsByName("phoneNumber")[1];

    if(response === false) {
        alert('false');
        arr.forEach(function(entry){
            entry.value = "";
        });
    }else{
        alert('true');
        arr.fn.value = response.firstName;
        arr.ln.value = response.lastName;
        arr.en.value = response.email;
        arr.pn.value = response.phone;
    }
}
```

**What I'm trying to do:**

if `response data === false`, loop through each element in `arr[]` and set its text value to empty `""`.

**What's happening:**

directly setting the values work (as shown in the `else{}` block), however looping or iterating through the array throws the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined`

**question:**

how can I loop through a collection of inputs stored in an array and set their values? Why is the `undefined` error being thrown?

Thanks!

EDIT: changing to the following does nothing; the `else{]` block still works fine, the loop is the problem I believe.

```
    function autoFill(response) {
    var arr = [];
    arr["fn"] = document.getElementsByName("firstName")[1];
    arr["ln"] = document.getElementsByName("lastName")[1];
    arr["em"] = document.getElementsByName("Email")[1];
    arr["pn"] = document.getElementsByName("phoneNumber")[1];

    if(response === false) {
        alert('false');
        arr.forEach(function(entry){
            entry.value = "";
        });

    }else{
        alert('true');
        arr["fn"].value = response.firstName;
        arr["ln"].value = response.lastName;
        arr["en"].value = response.email;
        arr["pn"].value = response.phone;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your array is empty.  Arrays are zero-based.

Comment: In one instance you're using the array as an object, the next as an array.

Comment: @SLaks: the array is not empty. There are index-0 inputs of the same name, that is why the code is referencing `[1]`.

Comment: @Andy: Which is preferable? I was under the impression arrays and objects in JS were essentially synonyms but if I should be doing it another way don't hesitate to enlighten me! :)

Comment: An object, but you would need to change the `forEach` to a `for (var k in obj)` loop. Objects are unordered, arrays are ordered by numeric index.

Comment: @Prefix: `arr` is empty.  Setting named properties does populate an array.  And, unless there are two elements with each of those names, `[1]` is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You need to use an object not an array and you should use "[dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)" for better clarity.</strike>

**EDIT**

I changed the code because I dont like to say "no you can't" so here's the new function with loop.

```
function autoFill(response) {
    var fill = {};
    for (var i=0; i < document.myForm.elements.length; i++) {
        var elm = document.myForm.elements[i]; // Get current element.

        fill[elm.name] = elm; // Associate fill[input name] with current input.

       if (elm.getAttribute("data-autofill") === "undefined" || 
           elm.getAttribute("data-autofill") === null) continue; // Continue if property data-autofill is not set.

        // If response have the input name as key, we set the value otherwise, it would be an empty string or unchecked.
        switch(elm.type) {
            case 'checkbox':
            case 'radio':
                response.hasOwnProperty(elm.name) ? fill[elm.name].checked = response[elm.name] : fill[elm.name].checked = false; // Checked if response if true.
                break;
            default:
                response.hasOwnProperty(elm.name) ? fill[elm.name].value = response[elm.name] : fill[elm.name].value = ""; // Set response text or a empty string.
       }
    }

    return fill; // Return object for later uses.
 }

 var myForm =  autoFill({
        firstName: "John", 
        check: true, 
        ni: "Not supposed to be set" // Won't set because he doesn't have the property data-autofill.
    });

  myForm.lastName.value = "Awesome"; // Now we can set values like this because we returned all form elements.
```

And the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zR9gP/).

Comment: Might be worth changing `arr` to `obj` to reduce confusion.

Comment: Perfect. One more question -- how could I do a similar loop for the `else{}` block? Each element has a unique value from the response object. I'd like to clean this up as much as possible to learn cleaner JS. Thank you.

Comment: You can't because each property have different values. It would be longer to do a loop than assigning them manually.

Answer (score 1):

To reuse the names in each area of the function, add them to an array and iterate over them **BUT** you need to ensure that the properties in `response` and your DOM element names match.

```
function autoFill(response) {

  var arr = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'Email', 'phoneNumber'];

  var obj = {};

  arr.forEach(function (el) {
    obj[el] = document.getElementsByName(el)[1];
  });

  if (response === false) {
    alert('false');
    for (var k in obj) {
      obj[k]['value'] = "";
    }
  } else {
    alert('true');
    arr.forEach(function (el) {
      obj[el]['value'] = response[el];
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store input fields into an array as 
arr[0], arr[1] and access them with index.

Answer (score 0):

you have declared:  var arr = []; then assigned arr.fn, arr.ln n so..

Either declare var arr = {}; or assign arr.fn, arr.ln as arr[0], arr[1].

When you assign,

```
     var arr = [];  
     arr["fn"] = document.getElementsByName("firstName")[1];
```

and observe the value of arr, it will be empty. so declare it as var arr= {}.